# Handling slow performance of the Entity Framework when eagerly loading with include statements?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am attempting to pull back a large number of relations form a SQL Server database using the entity framework for display on a summary web page and I am finding the performance of using many include statement in the query is abysmal.

The requirement is to display all of a single user's data on a page at once, generally, this isn't a huge amount of data, but fetching it does require traversing quite a few EF relations with a query something like this

```
var class = context.Class.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(Id))
                      .Include(a => a.Teacher.Address)
                      .Include(a => a.Teacher.Supplies.Notebooks)
                      .Include(a => a.Teacher.Supplies.Pencils)
                      .Include(a => a.Teacher.Supplies.Textbooks)
                      .Include(a => a.Teacher.Supplies.Erasers)
                      .Include(a => a.Students.Select(d => d.Supplies.Notebooks))
                      .Include(a => a.Students.Select(d => d.Supplies.Pencils))
                      .Include(a => a.Students.Select(d => d.Supplies.Textbooks))
                      .Include(a => a.Students.Select(d => d.Supplies.Erasers))
                      .Include(a => a.Configuration)
                      .Include(a => a.Payment.Payer.Address)
                      .Include(a => a.Payment.PaymentMethod)
                      .First();
```

That takes more than 10 seconds to run against a test database that contains minimal data.  However if I do this instead, performance takes ~1 second:

```
var class = context.Class.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(Id)).Include(a => a.Teacher.Address).First();
    class = context.Class.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(Id)).Include(a => a.Teacher.Supplies.Notebooks).First();
    class = context.Class.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(Id)).Include(a => a.Teacher.Supplies.Pencils).First();
    class = context.Class.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(Id)).Include(a => a.Teacher.Supplies.Textbooks).First();
    class = context.Class.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(Id)).Include(a => a.Teacher.Supplies.Erasers).First();
    class = context.Class.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(Id)).Include(a => a.Students.Select(d => d.Supplies.Notebooks)).First();
    class = context.Class.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(Id)).Include(a => a.Students.Select(d => d.Supplies.Pencils)).First();
    class = context.Class.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(Id)).Include(a => a.Students.Select(d => d.Supplies.Textbooks)).First();
    class = context.Class.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(Id)).Include(a => a.Students.Select(d => d.Supplies.Erasers)).First();
    class = context.Class.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(Id)).Include(a => a.Configuration).First();
    class = context.Class.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(Id)).Include(a => a.Payment.Payer.Address).First();
    class = context.Class.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(Id)).Include(a => a.Payment.PaymentMethod).First();
```

Is this really the best way to run a query to fetch all this data or am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: are you using code first or database first model?

Comment: It's the code first model.

Comment: using a view is an option but not as easy to implement when you use code first

Answer (score 0):

Well, I count 18 joins there, so it's not going to be *fast* by any means. However, depending on how you're testing this, your results may or may not be significant. In particular, if you're debugging or just running locally in general, everything is going to be slower in general. If you're using LocalDb, it's going to be slower than SQL Server. IIS Express is single-threaded, while IIS is multi-threaded, so that has an effect on performance as well.

First, and foremost, you should get something like [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) running with your project. This will let you actually separate the time it takes to load the page in general from the time it takes to run your queries, as well as give you visibility into the number and scope of queries being run. However, until you test on an actual production-like machine, with full IIS and SQL Server, you won't *really* know how this is going to perform.

If it's a real problem, you can look into creating a stored procedure to return all this information. That will be *much* quicker than anything EF can ever do as SQL Server can store the execution plan and optimize the queries. If you're finding that Entity Framework is too slow for your purposes, in general, you can also investigate using alternate ORMs like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net). Of course, you'll have a learning curve there, but if your primary focus is performance, you can pretty much always to better than Entity Framework, though you might lose some of the niceties in the process.

Comment: I am actually using a full version of SQL server, over the network as will occur in prod.  I am also running the query via a test case, rather than through IIS.  I was just surprised how slow it was given how little data there is to search through and I am worried how it will perform when there is more.

Comment: Well, like I said, with this many joins, you're better off with a stored procedure. Not only is EF not enormously efficient at joins, but it's got to materialize this entire object graph, which takes a while. A stored procedure would return a flattened structure you could utilize with a companion DTO class, for a much simpler structure and initialization. If you need the flexibility to do these joins on the fly, then you are probably going to have to move to a more efficient ORM like Dapper.

Comment: I agree that a SP would be much quicker but I would prefer to avoid that route.  There is no requirement for this to be lightning fast, just fast enough to display a web page in a reasonable amount of time.  It's just strange to me that the 2nd version is so much quicker because EF has to execute each query separately and then assemble the results itself.

Comment: I've now implemented 2 more tests that fetch multiple results sequentially rather than just a single result.  The interesting thing is that only the first result is slow and the subsequent calls are milliseconds.  It must be caching the query when they are run from within the same test.  Hopefully this will translate to a web environment and the query will only be slow the first time after the web-server starts.  What I don't know is if the query will remain cached indefinitely, but I guess that's another question.

Comment: The individual queries are quicker because there's an exponential effect to joins. The more joins you do in a single query the slower the entire query runs. SQL Server has to work harder to come up with an execution plan with 18 joins, versus one with 2-3. As far as a stored procedure goes, you really shouldn't look at it like a punishment. Stored procedures are awesome, and they're actually easier to work with when you really get down to it. Long and short, EF is just really not meant for this type of work, so you either deal with the slow or use something else.

Comment: Is it also possible that EF is loading data incrementally into the context? So 1st it loads a `Teacher` and `Address`, then it fetches `Supplies` and `Notebooks`, then it fetches `Pencils` etc zaq  if only the first result is slow that is likely to be because the data has been loaded into context, and no longer goes to the database. To test whether the problem is with EF or with the sql generated, I'd pull out that sql and run it directly on the database. `class.ToString()` will get you the query being used.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't explain why the `Include` technique is so slow, but this is how I would try to fetch that data:

```
var class = context
    .Class
    .Where(a => a.Id.Equals(Id))
    .First()
.Select(a => new 
{
    TA = a.Teacher.Address,
    TN = a.Teacher.Supplies.Notebooks,
    TP =a.Teacher.Supplies.Pencils,
    TT = a.Teacher.Supplies.Textbooks,
    TE = a.Teacher.Supplies.Erasers,
    SN = a.Students.Select(d => d.Supplies.Notebooks),
    SP = a.Students.Select(d => d.Supplies.Pencils),
    ST = a.Students.Select(d => d.Supplies.Textbooks),
    SE = a.Students.Select(d => d.Supplies.Erasers),
    a.Configuration,
    PA = a.Payment.Payer.Address,
    a.Payment.PaymentMethod
};
```

Does that improve the performance? If it does I'd be interested in the difference between the sql generated by the 2 techniques

Comment: This is returning an anonymous type rather than the class object which is not ideal.  I implemented it anyway to evaluate the performance, but it is as slow as the include version.  EF must evaluate it the same way.

Comment: It's actually worse than the original. In this form you're generating a vast amount of queries as everything is effectively lazy loaded. I count 22 queries not counting the initial.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, surely EF generates one query here?. Maybe you mean that it generates several sub-queries?.  What I don't understand is why zacs second technique is relatively efficient, but the first, which will generate 1 query is more than 10 times slower. I find it hard to believe that this difference is just SQL Server working harder to come up with  1 execution plan with 8+ joins versus 12 different ones with 2-3.

Comment: First() is evaluative. So before you start selecting everything else here, the query has already been sent. Then each additional relationship is lazy loaded, one branch at a time. Worse, because you're never selecting things like Teacher directly, it will be lazy loaded multiple times to fetch the sub relationships. All in all, a very inefficient way to get the information.

Comment: As far as the OP's two approaches, if you were to look at the generated queries for each, you would see why the first takes so long. EF is not very efficient with joins to begin with, but the query for 18 joins at various levels of the relationship would be huge. The other queries are far more simplistic to process.

Comment: More about Include performance here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/hh949853.aspx#8. Not convinced about First() causing queries to be split, if that's what you mean by evaluative. I'll go test when I'm back at my desk. Would Find(Id) work any better?